# Hide SKU from customer Completely (Whole Front End + Emails)

Tags: magento-1.9

I want to restrict SKU in magento 1.9.3.4 to admin only.

I tried several topics to do it across xml files and from emails with different methods.

Is there a way possible to completely hide SKU from customers in front end everywhere, including all sales emails to the customer, but only admins can see the SKU for the product.

Answer (score 0):

A quick "dirty" way would be to just add this style to your frontend css:

```
[class*="sku"] {display:none !important}
```

It targets all classes that contain "sku" in them and hides them.

Most elements that show sku usually have "sku" in their containing element classes.

For emails just add

```
.sku {display: none}
```

in `email-inline.css` and `email-non-inline.css`

Other than this, there is no easy way to completely hide sku in frontend and email (as far as I know), so you would have to remove each individual element manually.